# buttons with pictures - CSS problem

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a problem positionning a image in a button. Here's a  demo http://problem-demo.hit.bg/index.html
I want to position the picture in the middle of the button without pushing the span down. If I set the position to relative the span is being pushed, if I set it to absolute or fixed margin: auto isn't working, if I don't set margin to the span and the image is relative hte spans aren't in one line. Here's the sorce:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    margin-left:20px;
    display: inline-block;      
}
ul li a {
    float:left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a span {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: 54px;
}
ul li a img {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="download.png" alt="something" /><span>Download</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="download.png" alt="something" /><span>Download</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your demo link isn't working for me, but must it be an inline image? It sounds like your best bet would be to use a background image.

Comment: the site takes forever to load

Comment: What does your HTML/CSS look like? Also, that link might not be accessible from the US... if it is a Bulgarian site, we might not have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your code like this:

CSS:

```
li {
background:url(download.png) 20px 20px no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
```

Comment: Well I know but I want it to be with img tag, not with css.

Comment: @Nikolaj do img tags have a special purpose?

Comment: +1 `img` should only be used for content images. For decoration images, like icons, use `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your positioning and the setting of `display:block` to the image. If you just float both the image and the span to the left, it should display like you want it to.

However, I agree with @fabrik that a background image is the best solution.

Comment: Ok, if i have 4 items in the list, should I give each of them an id and with css to set the background image, or if there's a better solution what is it ?

Comment: @Nikolay If they all have the same background image, it´s easy. If they have different background images, you could give the `li` items a class (so you can reuse them if 2 or more share the same image) and use css sprites to speed up loading. Just look around on SO for css sprites.